# BeautifulSoup returns more than the floating point needed

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, currency-exchange-rates

I am trying to download/scrape the exchange rate of DKK to USD from a website. I have managed to almost get there. But this code returns more than the floating point no that I need.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.x-rates.com/table/"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup_packtpage = BeautifulSoup(page)
page.close()

#First, we will search for the table with class="views-view-grid" as follows:
ratestable = soup_packtpage.find("table",class_="tablesorter ratesTable")

# Find and print the value of Danish Krone to USD - only the floating point no.
print(soup_packtpage.find(text="Danish Krone").findNext('td').contents[0])
```

But this code returns more than the floating point no that I need.
it returns this mess:

```
<a href="/graph/?from=USD&amp;to=DKK">7.019776</a>
```

Please can someone enlighten me as to how to strip the string from this floating point result, so I can store it as a variable?

Comment: OK I fixed it myself I changed the 'td' tag to an 'a' tag, and now the code works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you want another `findNext('a')` before your contents. You want to keep the exchange rate, as it's not a currency in itself (e.g. it's precision doesn't need to be 2sf.).

For instance:

```
USD      Krone
$1.00    kr.7.02
$1000    kr.7019.78
```

I'm not familiar with Beautiful soup but this is what I'd try.

Or potentially find a currency conversion site that uses nice class names that you could use in your search.

In fact looking at the [API](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string), this should be sufficient:

```
print(soup_packtpage.find(text="Danish Krone").findNext('td').string)
```

As `string` looks through all the children of a tag.

Comment: Thanks Pureferret, This also solves a runtimeerror with my numbers 
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object

Now everything looks great. Thanks!